# Bypassing Exception Errors in using find_element_by statement in Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, exception, try-catch

When I use find_element_by statement and there is no matching element, it returns exception errors.
In this case, I'm trying to find 4 different elements and I want to pass onto the next finding when finding an element fails. I tried to use "Try - Except - Pass" statement, but it did not work.
Could you help solve my problem?

```
def selectSite():
    site1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='rec-flex-card-image-wrap' and contains(@aria-label,'%s')]" % str(siteNo1))
    site2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='rec-flex-card-image-wrap' and contains(@aria-label,'%s')]" % str(siteNo2))
    site3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='rec-flex-card-image-wrap' and contains(@aria-label,'%s')]" % str(siteNo3))
    site4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'book-now-button-')]")

    if site1.is_displayed():
        site1.click()
    elif site2.is_displayed():
        site2.click()
    elif site3.is_displayed():
        site3.click()
    elif site4.is_displayed():
        site4.click()
    else:
        print("no site available")
```

here is what I tried with try-catch statement

```
def selectSite():
    try:
    site1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='rec-flex-card-image-wrap' and contains(@aria-label,'%s')]" % str(siteNo1))
    site1.click()
    Except (NoSuchElementException):
      Pass:
    try:
    site2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='rec-flex-card-image-wrap' and contains(@aria-label,'%s')]" % str(siteNo2))
    site2.click()
    Except (NoSuchElementException):
      Pass:
    Try:
    site3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='rec-flex-card-image-wrap' and contains(@aria-label,'%s')]" % str(siteNo3))
    site3.click()
    Except (NoSuchElementException):
      Pass:
    Try:
    site4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'book-now-button-')]")
    site4.click()
    Except (NoSuchElementException):
      Pass:
```

Comment: Post your attempt at using `Try - Except - Pass`.

Comment: try/catch would work but I'd use find_elements instead.  If the returned array is empty nothing was found.

Comment: find_elements would be a good option. I will try it.

Comment: Yea you can do something like this `site1= len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath))` and then `if site1 > 0:` click on it.  Something like that

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I tried site1>0, site1="", site1=''
    site1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='rec-flex-card-image-wrap' and contains(@aria-label,'%s')]" % str(siteNo1))
    if site1 != "":
    site1.click()
    else:
     pass

Comment: site1 returns 1 using the len statement. but, when I tried     if site1 > 0: it returns syntax error

Comment: In addition, it is a clickable element so, converting it into len cannot be clicked later. so, I think I need to check if the string is empty instead

Comment: This is the return value
print (site1)
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="107feb9c304c5b8e8e9f63f6117e40e7", element="81a012bc-93e8-42ea-975e-734304923233")>]

Comment: just get the array of elements and check the size of the array.  Not sure what that is in python, but in java it'd be WebElementArray.isEmpty()... or check .size() for 0 or greater than 0.

Comment: I fixed the issue. thank you. I used while-try-if statement to solve the problem